# Sharing partitions between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i share my files from windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152326/how-do-i-share-my-files-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu)

I'm going to install W7 and Ubuntu 12.04.1, and my partition tab will look like this:

TOTAL HD SPACE: 320GB

- 120GB - Windows (15GB for the system, the rest for my games)
- 28GB  - Ubuntu /
- 150GB - Separate partition for sharing documents (music, videos, private files etc)

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and install. 
Make 150GB  as ntfs so that it can be seen in both windows and ubuntu.

For details please refer to [Can I change file systems inside of partitions within GParted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240063/can-i-change-file-systems-inside-of-partitions-within-gparted/)

Comment: This is I can't use an NTFS folder as /home

Comment: if not ntfs, it can't be seen by windows. Do you really need a home partition. All heavy files like media files can be copied to it and viewable in both windows and ubuntu. If it stays in /home it can't be accessed via windows.

Comment: Your /home folder (or partition) can be seen only by Linux. NTFS partitions - by Linux and Windows. Store your data accordingly.